# Copy multiple files to multiple folders using FileDialog in Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to build  vba code to copy files from a fixed folder to another folder.
My problem is that I want to specify where to copy the files using "`Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)`" and i don't know to do it.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub Copy_Folder()

    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim FromPath As String
    Dim ToPath As String
    Dim F As Object
    Set F = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)


    FromPath = "Z:\Templates\Template 2020"  
    ToPath = "C:\Users\ocosmele\Desktop\New folder"

    If Right(FromPath, 1) = "\" Then
        FromPath = Left(FromPath, Len(FromPath) - 1)
    End If

    If Right(ToPath, 1) = "\" Then
        ToPath = Left(ToPath, Len(ToPath) - 1)
    End If

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    If FSO.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
        MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    FSO.CopyFolder source:=FromPath, destination:=ToPath
    MsgBox "You can find the files and subfolders from " & FromPath & " in " & ToPath

End Sub
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y4PG2qr9tRM

Answer (score 0):

Just adjusted the first part of your code. Please read the code's comments and adjust it to fit your needs.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Copy_Folder()

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim targetFolder As Object

    Dim fromPath As String
    Dim intialPath As String
    Dim toPath As String

    ' Initialize the file system object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    fromPath = "C:\Temp\Test"
    intialPath = "C:\Users\ocosmele\Desktop\New folder"

    ' Ask user for the destination folder
    Set targetFolder = Application.fileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    ' Define the target folder dialog box properties and result
    With targetFolder
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = intialPath
        If .Show <> -1 Then
            MsgBox "You didn't select anything"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        toPath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

    If Right(fromPath, 1) = "\" Then
        fromPath = Left(fromPath, Len(fromPath) - 1)
    End If

    If Right(toPath, 1) = "\" Then
        toPath = Left(toPath, Len(toPath) - 1)
    End If


    If fso.FolderExists(fromPath) = False Then
        MsgBox fromPath & " doesn't exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    fso.CopyFolder Source:=fromPath, Destination:=toPath

    MsgBox "You can find the files and subfolders from " & fromPath & " in " & toPath

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: By any chance is it possible to select multiple folders as the destination path?

Comment: You could have a loop to keep asking for destination folders and end when the user cancels it. Or in a userform add a folder tree where the user can multi-select different folders.

Comment: I will try your suggestion